# how to use for-loop in array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var arr = [23,56,87,109];
var a23 = arr[0];
var a56 = arr[1];
var a87 = arr[2];
var a109 = arr[3];
```

How can I do that by using "for-loop"? THanks!

Comment: what are you doing with these variables?  can i just add them to the screen?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: any value you create inside the for loop will only be available in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
var arr = [23,56,87,109];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you want to assign it to N - separate variables.But you can use for loop like this :

```js
var arr = [23, 56, 87, 109];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  document.write(arr[i] + "<br>");
}
```